# Does gwt-bootstrap work outside of UiBinder?

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder, cssresource, gwt-bootstrap

All the examples for [gwt-bootstrap](http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/#) that I've come across show the use of Twitter Bootstrap styles inside a UiBinder XML file.

But what if I don't like UiBinder?

What if I want to use raw Widgets, or what if I want to use a `CssResource` client bundle, and write my own external CSS files?

Can gwt-bootstrap work outside the context of a UiBinder instance? If so, how? Code examples? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,You can without Uibinder. Just set up the widgets like any other non-uibinder GWT app and apply your style.

There is no condition that you have to use `UI binder`.